# UI freezes for a second when returning to the previous ViewController in Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having some trouble figuring out what's causing the UI to freeze for a second when I press the back button. It started happening after I added a background image to the viewController that I'm transitioning from. If I'm just using "white" as my backgroundColor, the transition doesn't freeze, it only freezes once I add the image.

Here is a gif of what it looks like...

https://gfycat.com/waryagileichidna

Here is the extension that I'm calling in my viewDidLoad to set the background image...

```
extension UIView {
    func addBackground(image:String) {
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        // screen width and height:
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    
        let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: "\(image)")
        imageViewBackground.alpha = 0.5
        // you can change the content mode:
        imageViewBackground.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        
        self.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
        self.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is calling code of this method?

Comment: Something needs to be on main thread. Please add more code.

Comment: Try to add transitioning code on Main thread

Comment: Try using the time profiler in Instruments to see what took the most time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding the below line to your `addBackground` method which you call in `viewDidLoad`.

```
imageViewBackground.clipsToBounds = true
```

I have a feeling this should solve it. That doesn't look like a freeze.